# Why is IIS NOT reading/using the site's Web.config, while IIS Manager is correctly accessing the Web.config?

Tags: iis, windows-10, iis-10

After "more time than was prudent" debugging an issue with handlers not being applied correctly, I've determined that the SiteRoot/web.config shown in IIS Manager is **not** actually used by IIS.

How do I know this? I've replaced `Web.config` with *invalid XML* - the site continues to run with default handlers and modules, while IIS Manager will, rightfully, throw an error on the *invalid XML*.

Information:

- The test/invalid Web.config *is not* being read by IIS, *or it would fail to parse*.

  - Static content *is* being served, with a root relative to the Web.config.
- The test/invalid Web.config *is* being read by IIS Manager, as it fails to parse/load (*as expected*).

  - Using "Explore" correctly opens up the folder the Web.config file exists in.
- The NTFS case-sensitivity is *disabled* [per this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/934201/388772). The same issue persists with both `web.config` and `Web.config` casings.
- The AppPool is running under a local account and the effective NTFS access has been verified.
- There are no related Windows Application or System event logs indicating there was an error reading or parsing the configuration.

**What might be occurring, and what further diagnosis can be done?**

Answer (score 1):

**While I have no idea what the initial cause was..**

One of these two things 'fixed' it. Unfortunately, the specific change was change was not identified.

1. Copied inetsvr's `applicationHost.config` from another machine.

   While this might have affected various globalModules, etc, *the same
   AppPool and Site definitions were used as they are installed through
   automation*.

   Due to this being a 'recovery' as VS Code *truncated* the original file, it is not feasible to diff for the relevant changes.
2. Deleted the contents of `C:\inetpub\temp\appPools`.

   Due to the timing of changes, I cannot confirm if this operation was more/less relevant than using a different applicationHost.

Comment: The actual cause can remain unknown, but your observation matches the internals of IIS. Web sites and their worker processes do not read `applicationHost.config` or `web.config` directly, but generated-on-the-fly config files located in `C:\inetpub\temp\appPools`. So, if something blocks the generation of such files after you change a setting, then sites/worker processes won't be able to pick the new setting. You can force the generation in certain ways to overcome the blocking, but again too little is known on the internals.